# Draw MS Paint User defined Rectangle on mouse move

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm now working with drawing some shapes on PANEL in C#. I have a problem with updating the current graphics. In other words I don't know how to create a current stage (where I will draw the current, let's say Rectangle) and draw it on Panel. I can draw a rectangle on `Mouse_down` event of Panel. But how to show the current Rectangle on `Mouse_move` Event, after the Mouse is pressed on Panel???  I don't want to use `Invalidate`. Because it clears all the panel drawing that were made before. Help me to show the current Rectangle shape when MOUSE IS MOVED , and draw it on Panel ONLY AFTER MOUSE IS RELEASED.

```
Pen p_white = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.White), pen_thickness);
int w1 = Math.Abs(starx - curx); int h1 = Math.Abs(stary - cury);
Rectangle rec_new = new Rectangle(starx, stary - h1, w1, h1);
gpath.Reset();
gpath.AddRectangle(rec_new);// code that adds Rectangle in MOUSE_MOVE EVENT

g.DrawPath(p, gpath); 
// Drawing the rectangle on Mouse Release Event. g was already binded to Panel.CreateGraphics
```

Comment: can you make your question more clear,,,,where did you want to show your drawing and where did you want to draw it..

Comment: I want my rectangle to drawn on panel, like MS Paint,  I get the starting point on Mouse_Down event, then when I move mouse my rectangle automatically changes its size like in MS Paint, then its draw(saves) only after the Mouse is Released.

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to use Invalidate() to call the Paint method.

And you have to move **all** your drawing there! so this line

```
g.DrawPath(p, gpath);
```

goes into the Paint event like this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, gpath);
```

Since you are building up a GraphicsPath this is a small change. If you build up your drawing like if you create more GraphicsPaths, they all must be drawn there.

You cannot build up a drawing by drawing repeatedly on the panel like you would on paper; you must somehow store the draw actions. This sound tedious but here you really have to move just the one line.

And: as you progress it will give you the chance for unlimited undos, scaling etc..

Comment: Thank you, that works, but another problem appears, my drawn rectangle scales down, and changes its coordinates. Why? I understood that it happens when Invalidata(); is called

Comment: It doesn't. Invalidate simply makes Paint happen. So the coordinates in your path now refer to something different. Without the code of MouseDown, -Up, -Move and Paint we can't tell why.

Comment: ..But I can guess: Some events probably refer to the panel, others to the form, yes? Make sure all refer to the panel, so their coordinates mean the same! Each control has a Paint, a MouseUp etc event! And so has the form. (Which __is__ a Control)

Comment: No, now I don't paint on `Panel`, I do Painting on PictureBox, I also have mouse_down, mouse_move,mouse_up related to my Picture_box events.   I have my foreground image drawn correctly, from mouse_down point to current point of mouse_move it draw me rectangle perfectly, scales up, scales down. But after I release my mouse, MOUSE_UP event happens. So my Rectangle scales down and shifts upward, and to left  from the point where I released my mouse i.e rectangle end points.

Comment: Can this problem caused by background image?? I have default BG as picture of white paper and made sizes same for bg and picturebox

Answer (score 0):

See this note from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4.aspx):

> Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The
>   background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its
>   parent.

Unfortunately this means that we can't do this the simple way - by putting a transparent image control of some sort over another control.  WinForms doesn't do it.

One method I've used is to do all temporary drawing (selections, incomplete drawings, etc) inside a 'foreground' buffer, and use the `Paint` event of the background image control to draw the temporary objects as needed.

Given a `PaintBox` control that contains the image, you can use the `Paint` event to draw the foreground buffer as required, giving full transparency options.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Bitmap Foreground;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create foreground buffer same size as picture box
        Foreground = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        // Draw a blue ellipse in the foreground buffer for something to see
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Foreground))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 10, 10, 300, 100);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Foreground, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Assuming your picture box has something in it, this will draw a Blue ellipse over the top of it.

Whenever you want to change the overlaid foreground image you need to ensure that the `PaintBox` control will be redrawn.  Use the `Invalidate` method to tell Windows that the control needs to be repainted.

Some more code:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            e.Handled = true;

            // draw foreground to background
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
                g.DrawImage(Foreground, 0, 0);

            // clear foreground
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Foreground))
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            e.Handled = true;

            // a random number source - probably better at form level
            var rnd = new Random();

            // draw a new random ellipse
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Foreground))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 30 + rnd.Next(500), 30 + rnd.Next(500));
            }

            // tell Windows to redraw the paintBox to show new foreground image
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Pressing `Enter` commits the foreground buffer to the image in the `PaintBox`, pressing `Space` generates a random new red ellipse in the foreground buffer.

The same base technique can be used for all sorts of things, like pasting images to specific locations (paste into and move around in the foreground buffer, then copy foreground on top of background when done), showing selection objects, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that works, but another problem appears, my drawn rectangle scales down, and changes its coordinates. Why? I understood that it happens when Invalidata(); is called

Comment: This `pictureBox1_Paint` and this `Form1_KeyDown` is mixing the Controls it refers to and so the coordinates will mean different things; either make all things happen in the panel's events or correct for the panel's offest!

Comment: @user3505681 If the image you're drawing on is transformed in any way - scaled, translated, scaled, etc - you'll need to perform the same transforms in your drawing code.  I used a PictureBox to hold the image with no scaling or other manipulations, inside a Panel to handle scrolling as required.